# Detect if string is a Date with an exact given format

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, format

I'd like to check whether a string does represent a Date with an given format.
I tried `Date.parse(string, format)` but it parses the string to date even if it's in a whole different format. E.g.:

```
Date.parse("2015-07-04T23:10:00.000+02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ") // Parsed as a date
Date.parse("2000", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ") // Parsed as a date also`
```

I don't want to parse the second row as a date, because its not in the required format.
I also tried `Date.parseExact()` method of [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com)  but it didn't parsed the date if I provided a timezone and a format like above.

**The right solution was based on RobG's comment:** (but thanks to **everyone** for helping me)

```
moment("2015-07-04T23:10:00.000+02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", true).isValid()
```

Every other solution succeeded the parsing even if the input was only a year which I tried to avoid. The last parameter "true" stands for the "strict" parsing which provides exactly the output that I was looking for.

Comment: You could try [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.parse), Date.parse only accepts one argument, any additional arguments are ignored. If you only want to check one format, it's only 3 or 4 lines of code. But if your requirements go beyond that, use a library. There are plenty with good parsers and formatters, e.g. [*Fecha.js*](https://momentjs.com), [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com).

Comment: using a custom regular expression might not be a bad idea

Comment: But Date.parse will parse everything that can be a date which I do not want, I want to parse only in that case if the string matches the given format otherwise fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage **MomentJS** and its function `.format()`

How does it work? here is the documentation, it's fairly simple, you wanna use your string in combination with the format string.

[MomentJS .format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

And here is the quick demo Fiddle:

```
var myString = "2015-07-04T23:10:00.000+02:00";
var formatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
if (moment(myString, formatString)._i == myString) console.log("GOOD");
```

[1-liner with momentJS](https://jsfiddle.net/dd9jf0o8/)

I basically format your string in targeted format then check if the result matches your string.

Worth noting is that MomentJS is (IMHO) the best date and time lib for JS. I never found a reason to venture beyond it since I discovered it, after using some of the less capable libs in the past.

**If you don't wanna use lib, making a regex to suit your needs is a viable alternative of similar length.**

Altho, if you intend to work with a lot of dates/times, MomentJS is still a way to go as it offers so many useful things which cannot be done by regexes alone.

Comment: `moment("2015-07-04T23:10:00.000+02:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", true)` does it in one. But it's not a good idea to answer with a library that isn't mentioned or tagged in the OP.

Comment: @RobG - Very Smooth! I think it's a good recommendation since he already tried using DateJS and MomentJS is by far superior and he never mentioned he needs a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expression to check if input matches the format and parse it if it does?

```
reg=new RegExp(/[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\+[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/);
str="2015-07-04T23:10:00.000+02:00";
date=new Date(str);
if(str.match(reg) && date.toString()!='Invalid Date')
  {
    Date.parse(str);
  }
```

Edited to add date check.

Comment: That doesn't check if it's a valid date.

Comment: That is far too simple regex to match dates. It will match str="2015-99-99T23:10:00.000+02:00" and a lot of other non-date values. I would use this ONLY if I was 100% sure it's a valid date I am getting. Well, I wouldn't even then because I believe in sanitation of the data I got so I would retailor regex ;)

Comment: That addition made all the difference ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, verification FTW.